Why are method sections usually impersonal, when the main text isn’t?
There are generally two possible ways to present experiments and analyses in academic writing, which I label as follows for the purpose of this question:

Personal, also referred to as active or first person, e.g.:

We discombobulated the giraffes in the flux compensator until we determined them to be transmogrified per Hinterwald’s criterion.


Impersonal, also referred to as passive or third person, e.g.:

Giraffes were discombobulated in the the flux compensator until they were determined to be transmogrified per Hinterwald’s criterion.



Most fields, journals, etc. nowadays have a clear preference towards the personal writing style. However, there is one peculiar exception:
In many experimental fields, it is common to separate experimental and statistical details into method sections, which are usually an appendix to the main paper. These are most commonly written in impersonal style, although the main papers are exclusively written in personal style for decades. Why?
What I considered so far:

Actions described in the methods section are occasionally performed by others than the authors of the paper, e.g., lab assistants, central facilities, or robots. However, these actions may also be described in the main text (albeit more rarely). For example, you will often find authors writing in the main text that they sequenced some organisms when the actual sequencing was almost certainly done by a company or central facility.

Method sections receive very little love. They are often badly written, unorganised, not really peer-reviewed or copy-edited, typeset by the authors in Word, etc. Thus the students that usually write them may be in cultural inertia and just copy the style from papers they find, since nobody bothers to tell them to do differently. While this is a conceivable reason, I do not consider it to be very plausible.


Please note that this question is not about:

Whether personal or impersonal writing is better for method sections or in general. On this, see this question and links therein.

When impersonal writing is used to describe something that was not done for the paper in question, usually in a previous publication.

How to exactly separate these styles, and whether Strunk and White could correctly distinguish the active and passive voice.



Interesting question. Glad you asked it. I hadn't thought about this until a couple of months ago when I had the chance to mentor some postdocs on how to review.

All of my papers are entirely typeset in Word.

Also, as a linguist I'll quibble that "active" and "first-person" are different things. "The RAs evaluated the participants for ..." is active but not first-person. But, I do think your summary phrasing of "(im)personal" is apt.

@AzorAhai: … which is more or less exactly why I chose it this way and used “also referred to as” for the alternatives.

... "also referred to as" implies synonymy.

@AzorAhai: Well, some people do use it synonymously, whether we like it or not. Just see the answers so far.

Third person but not passive voice or impersonal: "The authors propose...". Impersonal, not passive voice: "A computer recorded the output".  The passive voice often serves to give an impersonal tone ("an impersonal tone is served by the use of the passive voice" is hardly an improvement) but they're not the same thing linguistically even to an amateur.

Ah for the days of longer style guides that actually explained things. If I pull out my American Institute of Physics "AIP Style Manual" (Fourth edition, 1990) one finds:

9. "I," "we," and impersonal constructions
(1) The old taboo against using the first person in formal prose has long been deplored by the best authorities and ignored by some of the best writers...
(2) The passive is often the most natural way to give prominence to the essential facts:
Air was admitted to the chamber.
(Who cares who turned the valve?) But avoid the passive if it makes the syntax inelegant or obscure...

My bolding.
If who specifically performs the experiment matters, it isn't a good description of how to do the experiment. But, in analyzing the data and discussing the implications, that is on the authors and what they did.

This adds very little to Anyon’s answer, so my comments to that answer mostly apply here as well. In particular, you’ll often find descriptions of the experiment in the main paper and descriptions of the statistical analysis in the methods. Also mind that I am pretty aware of the general arguments for and against personal and impersonal writing, but they fail to explain the custom in question.

@Wrzlprmft - fair enough, I got caught up in doing actual work after starting to write an answer around the same time. The burdens of wanting to be paid...

To answer your main question (and a good one!):

These are most commonly written in the impersonal style, although the main papers are exclusively written in active style since decades. Why?

I recently had a couple of experienced editors from top fisheries journals
talk to a group of postdocs and early career scientists I mentor/co-mentor.
They talked about this specific topic.
They personally preferred 3rd person for methods because they felt it should not matter who conducted the methods.
Thus, the methods should be impersonal.
However, they also noted they prefer well written and understandable papers rather than fighting over 1st versus 3rd person.
Personally, I usually write my methods primarily in first person and use some 3rd person simply to vary structure.
I will also specifically use 3rd person if somebody else did the work such as a contract lab analyzing samples or a national monitoring program collecting field samples.
For your other considerations, here's my musing:

What I considered so far:
Actions described in the methods section are occasionally performed by others than the authors of the paper, e.g., lab assistants, central facilities, or robots. However, these actions may also be described in the main text (albeit more rarely). For example, you will often find authors writing in the main text that they sequenced some organisms when the actual sequencing was almost certainly done by a company or central facility.
Method sections receive very little love. They are often badly written, unorganised, not really peer-reviewed or copy-edited, typeset by the authors in Word, etc. Thus the students that usually write them may be in cultural inertia and just copy the style from papers they find, since nobody bothers to tell them to do differently. While this is a conceivable reason, I do not consider it to be very plausible.

I think the inertia comment is on to something.
I know of very few people who take scientific writing courses at the graduate level so most people learn from their advisors and committee members who edit their work.
So, "good `nuff" writing for methods gets the section done.
Introductions are almost always 3rd person until the aims/objectives/hypotheses of the paper.
Results and discussion can be either.
Personally, I think both active and passive and 1st and 3rd person have their places.
Broadly, a well written paper can be use either style, or, probably better written using both.
I think a well written paper (e.g., understandable, clear, and concise) is more important than the style choices.
Switching between the two can help by adding in variability.
For example,

We observed fish swam farther during the day (some numbers and test statistics here...). Males swam less than females (more numbers etc) other than during pre-spawning events when males swam more than females (more numbers etc.).

changes from first person to third person.
As I've grown as a writer, I think knowing the rules so you know when you can break them to improve your writing is important.

They personally preferred 3rd person for methods because they felt it should not matter who conducted the methods. – Did they say anything on applying the same argument to the main text? (Also see my first point under What I considered so far.)

I remember the comments about the methods. I'll update my answer with your other ideas

Many take the view that the it makes sense to write the methods in an impersonal style, as it really should aim to be purely objective. The platonic ideal then is that the same methods could be carried out identically by another group (that happen to have the same equipment), so why emphasize the person(s) over the procedures? This can be contrasted with other sections of a paper, which often incorporate some degree of interpretation, which is inherently more subjective. Further, as the AIP style guide (4th ed.) put it:

The passive is often the most natural way to give prominence to the essential facts:
Air was admitted to the chamber.
(Who cares who turned the valve?)

Another potential issue is that a methods section written in the active voice can easily end up with a large number of sentences starting with, or containing, a first person pronoun.

That would essentially be the first thing I listed under What I considered so far: Going by this, it’s rather a question of what you write as opposed to where you write it. However, in the journals and field in question, you will find the same kind of statement in personal style in the main text and in impersonal style in the methods. Relatedly, the AIP style guide also advocates for personal style on occasion, which would also apply to method sections. (Of course, your answer may still accurately describe the bad reason why people do things the way they do.)

BTW: The fourth edition of the AIP style guide is from 1990, after which it seems to have been discontinued. That also explains the reference to abstract journals in the section in question.

The publication year is why I opted for "put it" rather than "puts it" (or, should I say, "as it was put in"). Yes, the advice in the AIP style guide is what I consider the sane position, i.e.  aim for clarity and readability rather than 100% sticking to one voice. However, in other places you commonly see the recommendation to keep the voice constant within each section (certainly, varying it too much can be jarring), which is presumably part of why you see such marked differences between different sections.

Another potential issue is that a methods section written in the active voice can easily end up with a large number of sentences starting with, or containing, a first person pronoun. – In terms of redundancy and stylistic bore, the method sections in question have far worse problems than this. Most of them contain long sequences of grammatically identical sentences along the lines of: “X were Yed with Z.”

The publication year is why I opted for "put it" rather than "puts it" (or, should I say, "as it was put in"). – Ah, I mistook that for a grammatical-number error.

I don't think it has anything to do with who did what and whether the personal involvement matters - it is about the purpose of the sections in a paper. The methods section, historically, is meant to allow others to repeat what you did. In that respect, it is more like a protocol (but in narrative form) rather than in an experiment report (with interpretations and conclusions). It is supposed to be dry, short and informative. Now of course, in the days of (seemingly unlimited) online space, this section is changing. It is becoming more elaborate (because people realized critical details often didn't fit in a methods section with a max word count) and stylized even (e.g. in the STEM field you increasingly see a key resources table - all with the goal of maximizing the chance of reproducibility by others).
Put differently: the main text is a scientific narrative that advances insight and theory, the methods section is there to allow others to repeat the work that led to those new insights (but that may also leave openings for other interpretations of the data - this is how science progresses).
